# Why the person at back on a two wheeler feels hard to listen to sound of the person riding

Tags: waves, experimental-physics, acoustics

Situation

> Today while I was riding a two wheeler(activa) and was talking simultaneously my sister behind me complaint that she wasn't able to hear anything I was saying

but I dont get it when we are in a closed space like car there is no problem with sound but when we ride a bike or a cycle the person at back finds it difficult to hear what the  person in front is saying

---

I believe the observation should be based on

1. Compression and rarefractions
2. Doppler effect as both source and observer are moving
3. Based on one comment I believe that since I am speaking in direction opposite to that of air, is it possible that there is super position of waves in different phase resulting in a decrease in amplitude

Is there a more logical explanation

Comment: I think inserting the lines into the post makes it look worse.

Comment: @Anusha both the source and the observer are moving with same speed so the main thing here is the fast moving air . In your frame the wind is going back and you are speaking against it. I think this makes the difference.

Comment: @Anusha superposition of which **different** waves ?

Comment: @Ankit some sort of fluctuation in air pressure maybe. You got some explanation?

Comment: @Anusha you asked this  question then this means that something invoked you to think of superposition and then you should be able to think of superposition of what is possible here . I don't know of something's superposition here .. but one thing is that since the air is moving you barely create a region of pressure variation and in order to create an audible sound you would have to scream loud such that the molecules really got close irrespective of their opposite motion..

Comment: By two wheeler you mean a bicycle or a motorcycle? Or maybe e-bike?